# Secure Persistant Caching in an iOS Static Framework

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, persistent-storage, ios-frameworks

I am currently in the process of writing a static iOS framework that connects developers to my API and returns to them objectified information at their user's requests. However, in order for this framework to be worthwhile, one of the requirements is that this framework must be able to cache the information locally and return an offline copy when a network connection is unavailable. I am aware that I can store this information in NSUserDefaults but there may be a  case where the information that is cached may be private and the local developer should not be able to have access by guessing the proper key. I believe that best approach will involve some sort of encryption but I wanted to see if there were any other storage options available to a static framework other than NSUserDefaults.

I would like to keep my data in an objectified format if possible. Two solutions I would be interested in exploring would be to save my offline data in either SQLite or CoreData. However, with both of these approaches I am concerned about how these files would be stored in the framework (I already have an embedded framework) and the security issues of having the schema for these files available in the bundle for the developer to see.

Another solution that I am looking into would be to see if iOS supports any tools such as gzip that could be used to password protect my files until they are used by the framework.

Has anyone successfully overcome any of these issues? Is there anything else I should be looking into besides the previously mentioned possible solutions? Any advice will be warmly welcomed.

Thanks.

P.S. Does anyone know of any resources I could go read relating to iOS Security or static frameworks? Either would be very helpful.

Comment: What type of data? Files?

Comment: The data will be a list of objects. No filtering or ordering required. They can be saved in any type of format so long as they can not be read from outside of the framework. These objects are rigidly defined by my API and will not need be changed once they have been cached.